# How can I restart a process only if it fails but not if it exits normally (or with certain return codes)?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, java, bash-scripting

I'm experiencing a strange problem that's probably related to hardware initialization. I'm working on a Java-based automatic data acquisition system that runs on an SBC with Ubuntu 16.04. The data acquisition program is started through cron for now, although I'm planning to switch to systemd.

It starts and runs fine if I reboot the system. However, if it's powered off and cold-started (which is the normal way), the program crashes with the error `free(): corrupted unsorted chunks`. If I start it again, it seems to run fine. I need to figure out why and hopefully will, but it may take some time, and in the meantime the system needs to be tested further and I need a workaround that will restart it if it crashes. Just adding a delay doesn't help.

What I would like to do is to restart the Java process or reboot the system from the bash wrapper script, but only if it crashes. If it exits with the zero exit code (or, ideally, with any code from the predetermined set of allowable exit codes), it should not be restarted and the script should also exit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can write a Bash script, schedule this script instead of your program:

```
#!/bin/bash
myprogram
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
    myprogram
done
```

This script will restart your program until it exits with a 0 error code (indicating a success). Also, rebooting the whole system seems *slightly* overkill to me.

Comment: Thank you very much! I suppose I could use `if` and `break` and change this to an equivalent of a do-while loop and call the program only in one place (it has a few arguments that I'd rather not repeat) and log the exit code `$?`. Is there a simple and elegant way to use a set of allowable exit codes (other than with logical operators, e.g. `[ $? -ne 0 ] && [ $? -ne 73]` )?

Comment: The soultion that comes to my mind is to use a list of exit codes, and check if `$?` is in that list. However, the solution proposed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/8063398/4482039 is not what I would personnally call "simple"... As for the problem of not repeating arguments, you can store them (or the entire command line) is a variable. I am not a fan of counterfeit `do...while` loops, but that's personnal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Nathan.Eilisha Shiraini solution, taking into account [Emulating a do-while loop in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16489942/548473)

```
#!/bin/bash
while : ; do
    myprogram
    [[ $? -ne 0 ]] || break
done
```